# how overcome this error "com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log"

Tags: java, database, mongodb, jdbc, nosql

I am working with java program connected with MongoDB when I run the program it will show an error but code is working.
MongoDB has a database called MongoDB and inside that, there is a collection called seatbooking with two columns(name,seatnumber).
This is my code:

```
MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient("localhost", 27017);
System.out.println("connection is established");

MongoDatabase mongoDatabase = mongoClient.getDatabase("MongoDB");
MongoCollection mongoCollection = mongoDatabase.getCollection("seatbooking");

Document document = new Document("name","shenal");
document.append("seatnumber",20);
mongoCollection.insertOne(document);
```

when I run this code my output is:

```
> Mar 09, 2020 12:41:36 PM
> com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log INFO: Cluster created
> with settings {hosts=[localhost:27017], mode=SINGLE,
> requiredClusterType=UNKNOWN, serverSelectionTimeout='30000 ms',
> maxWaitQueueSize=500}
> **connection is established** Mar 09, 2020 12:41:36 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log INFO: Cluster
> description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out
> Mar 09, 2020 12:41:36 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log
> INFO: Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:1, serverValue:309}]
> to localhost:27017 Mar 09, 2020 12:41:36 PM
> com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log INFO: Monitor thread
> successfully connected to server with description
> ServerDescription{address=localhost:27017, type=STANDALONE,
> state=CONNECTED, ok=true, version=ServerVersion{versionList=[4, 2,
> 2]}, minWireVersion=0, maxWireVersion=8, maxDocumentSize=16777216,
> logicalSessionTimeoutMinutes=30, roundTripTimeNanos=5168100} Mar 09,
> 2020 12:41:36 PM com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger log INFO:
> Opened connection [connectionId{localValue:2, serverValue:310}] to
> localhost:27017
```

Comment: what is wrong here? Where it's written error. This seems to be the logger class

Comment: how to avoid that error

Comment: What is the error I don't understand

Answer (score 0):

The logging output doesn't show any result for the `insertOne` operation.

If you are using MongoDB Java Driver version prior to 4.0, there is no acknowledgement object returned. But, the version 4's `insertOne` method returns a [InsertOneResult](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.0/apidocs/mongodb-driver-core/com/mongodb/client/result/InsertOneResult.html?is-external=true) object. This is a new feature in 4.0 (in prior version's the method returned a `void`).

You can use the following code to check the insert's outcome as follows (with version 4.0):

```
try {
    InsertOneResult insertResult = collection.insertOne(document);
    System.out.println("Document inserted with ID: " + insertResult.getInsertedId());
}
catch(MongoWriteException e) {
    // write failure happened, handle it here...
}
```